# Angular Datatable - override button CSS

Tags: css, angular5, angular-datatables

I use angular 5 and angular-datatable.

I want to apply "btn btn-success" class on custom button

This is what I tried :

```
this.dtOptions = {
     ...
 buttons: [
     {
       text: 'Sélection',
       className: 'btn btn-success',
       ...
     }
  ]
}
```

This is the result :
[image]

The class is added but it keeps 'dt-button' class before that overrides some attributes as you can see on image

But I don't find how to remove it...

How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found :

```
 this.dtOptions = {
 dom: 'Blfrtip',
 initComplete:  function (settings, json) {
    $('.button').removeClass('dt-button');
 },
 buttons: [
    'print',
    'excel',
     {
          text: 'Sélection',
          className: 'table-button button btn btn-success',
          ...
        }
     ]
}
```

Now It works !

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in Angular 13 and Bootstrap 5 and was able to resolve it as follows:

```
initComplete: function (settings: any, json: any) {

    $('button').removeClass('dt-button');
    $('button').removeClass('buttons-excel');
    $('button').removeClass('buttons-html5 ');
      
  },
  buttons: [{
    extend: 'excel',
    text: 'Exportar',
    className: "btn btn btn-dark float-end",
  }],
```

[button color change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkyzL.png)

If the styles are not removed first, the one you want to apply does not apply.